# How to get what data-model provide in Teamcity email notification freemarker

Tags: java, teamcity, freemarker

I'm doing something about customization for Teamcity notification emails and I'm following [Customizing Notifications](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Customizing+Notifications). Accoring to it, the data-model Teamcity provide is

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="project" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SProject" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="buildType" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SBuildType" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="build" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SBuild" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="agentName" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="buildServer" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SBuildServer" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="webLinks" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.WebLinks" -->

<#-- @ftlvariable name="var.buildFailedTestsErrors" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="var.buildShortStatusDescription" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="var.buildChanges" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="var.buildCompilationErrors" type="java.lang.String" -->

<#-- @ftlvariable name="link.editNotificationsLink" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="link.buildResultsLink" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="link.buildChangesLink" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="responsibility" type="jetbrains.buildServer.responsibility.ResponsibilityEntry" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="oldResponsibility" type="jetbrains.buildServer.responsibility.ResponsibilityEntry" -->
```

And it's said that

> the code can be used in IntelliJ IDEA to edit the template with
>   completion

I don't have IntelliJ IDEA so that I wonder is there any other way for me to check what's inside each data-model?

For your information, I have researched something about how to create the data-model and template under [Getting Started](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart.html).

AFAK, if the object exported to template conform to the JavaBean spec, I can get the attribute by the variable name. For example, for the Class like below,

```
/**
 * Product bean; note that it must be a public class!
 */
public class Product {

    private String url;
    private String name;

    // As per the JavaBeans spec., this defines the "url" bean property
    // It must be public!
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    // As per the JavaBean spec., this defines the "name" bean property
    // It must be public!
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I can get the attribute of data-model like below,

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome ${user}!</h1>
  <p>Our latest product:
  <a href="${latestProduct.url}">${latestProduct.name}</a>!
</body>
</html>
```

However, why does `build.name` in Teamcity notification template can work? I haven't saw neither `getName` method or `name` variable at http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/8.1/jetbrains/buildServer/serverSide/SBuildType.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SBuiltType` inherits `getName()` from `BuildTypeIdentity`, so that's why `build.name` works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got what's point here. However, I can see getExtendedName() in SBuiltType, why build.extendedName return nothing in template.

Comment: My first thought was that `getExtendedName()` returns `null`, but it shouldn't according the javadoc. Is `build.getExtendedName??` `true` (that is, do we have that method at all)?

Comment: Hmmm, don't know why but succeeded to get the value of build.extendedName this time. Thanks for your help.